# Not able to call javascript funtion from c# in Asp.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

This issue is discussed many times on this site, but nowhere I found solution to my problem.

I have performed following steps.

**1. Created a JS function.**

```
 function showModal() {
            alert("called");
       }
```

**2. Added a script manager in .aspx file**

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

**3. Created a method in .cs file**

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()] 
        protected void register_user(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showModal", "javascript:showModal(); ", true);
            log.Debug("register_user is called");


        }
```

But It is not calling JS function.

Comment: @Div. That was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is due to, you have not closed your javascript function:

```
function showModal() {
            alert("called");
}
```

OR you can also try this:

Replace your this line:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showModal", "javascript:showModal(); ", true);
```

with

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Message", "showModal(); ", true); // correct
```

Comment: I modified as per your suggestion. still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing so many stuff.

If you want to add javascript from Code Behind to your html. This should be located in some global event `Page_Load` or `PreRender`.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showModal", "YourJavascriptCode", true);
```

If you want to call method in the aspx from AJAX call, which should return response

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()] 
    public static string register_user(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //you can return a class->Json
         return stuff;
    }
```

If you want to execute javascript on client click of your button. I suppose you want this !

```
    YourButton.Attributes["onclick"]= "javaScriptFunction()";
    //if you want to not execute server side
    YourButton.Attributes["onclick"]= "javaScriptFunction(); return false";
```

Here the easiest way for adding javascript function to your asp button.

```
<asp:Button ID="RegisterBtn" runat="server" Text="Register"  OnClientClick="showModal()" onclick="register_user"/>
```

Comment: hey. This is just a demo JS function. I need to add more lines of code after it runs successfully.

Comment: @DKR you can add hundreds of lines of code, if you don't understand this 3 things what they are doing, you can't add even 1 line

Comment: as per your modification in answer, what If i want to call JS function on a button click, not on pageload?

Comment: @DKR you are not calling anything with RegisterStartupScript, you are adding script to the html. Call is executed, when FIRST attach your javascript method to the button attribute onclick and after that you click the button. Also first the client side is executed and after that the server side.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think calling Js function from aspx.cs is a good idea.

Anyway, from your snippet, just change to this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showModal", "showModal()", true);
```

Take note at the 3rd parameter: `"showModal()"`

And also, your JS function "showModal()", does it work by clicking this button? `<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="showModal();"/>`

Answer (score 0):

**What worked for me is:**

Instead of -

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showModal", "javascript:showModal(); ", true);
```

I added -

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(), "Message", "showModal();", true);
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add namespace

using System.Web.UI;

Replace your this line:

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showModal", "javascript:showModal(); ", true);

with

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "showModal();", true);

it works fine